# Remove attr isn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a script like accordion, 
this my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.film').click(function(){
        $('.film').attr('id','activeMenu');
        $('#film').slideToggle();       
    });

    $('#activeMenu').click(function(){
        $('.film').removeAttr("id");        
    });

});
```

this is style of activeMenu when it clicked

```
.activeMenu{
    background:#C9FF26; 
}
```

if i click .film and click again , `id=activeMenu` isn't removed

anyone know this problem?
thanks

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well.

Comment: For reference, rather than using `$('.film').attr('id','activeMenu');` you can simply use `this.id = 'activeMenu'`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem happens because at the time you call `$('#activeMenu').click(...)` the element you're targeting doesn't actually have that ID.

You could *potentially* use `$(document).on('click', '#activeMenu', ...)` (i.e. a delegated event handler) that will work even if `#activeMenu` doesn't yet exist but I can't help but feel that this would be the wrong solution.  It's almost *never* necessary to dynamically add or remove an ID on an existing element.  A proper solution would depend on exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ZachL the correct solution almost certainly _doesn't_ involve removing any ID attributes.  The presence of that attribute shouldn't be used for signalling purposes.

Comment: but if  i use that, #activeMenu is never added :(

Comment: @user2924643 so please describe the actual result you're trying to achieve.  Adding and removing the ID is almost certainly not the correct means of getting there.

Answer (score -4):

You need to use .on method to register click event on #activeMenu

```
$('#activeMenu').on('click',function(){
        $('.film').removeAttr("id");        
    });
```

Comment: `click(..)` just works fine. Problem is that the ID isn't there yet. Also, the way you are using on is the wrong way around.

Comment: I still don't think this will work. You have to use it like `$('.always-present-parent-of-activeMenu').on('click', "#activeMenu' function...` Otherwise it will still loose the event handler when the id is removed.